# How do I get a list of twitter bootstrap 3 colors?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-sass

I'm using the twitter bootstrap sass 3.0.3.0 gem which should correspond to the latest twitter bootstrap 3.0.3. I was looking at the 'customize' section of the lESS variables but cannot find too many colors. How do I get a list of colors provided by bootstrap 3?

For example, searching for blue [bootstrap 3 docs](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#less-variables) returns no result. Whereas searching for blue at [bootsrap 2 docs](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/customize.html) shows the color blue.

Thanks!

Comment: updated my answer after re-reading your question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They no longer name their classes or variables that way, because they are trying in release 3 to be more semantic, ie naming stuff for what it does rather than what it looks like.  So @Blue might have become @btn-default-color.

That is better in the long run because your implementation might make it green, so @blue does not adequately describe it anymore.  Unfortunately unless you know color hex codes this makes it a little harder.

You can always (in a modern browser) right click the color you see and choose "inspect element", steal the color from the CSS code on the right hand side and then search for THAT color code in the docs.

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#less-variables

Comment: It's still awkward that if I want to color my navbar 'blue', then I have to use @btn-bar-color or something. Or maybe that makes sense?

Comment: right.  Semantic naming as it relates to HTML and CSS is tags, classes, IDs, and attributes describing but not specifying the content they enclose.   Bootstrap in particular is reused by millions of people, who override color values with their own, but can talk about it on sites like this interchangeably... oh just update `@btn-default-color` and your button default color will change, if they used the old naming scheme i'd say just update `@blue` and with "black" things can get confusing quickly

Comment: OK. Thanks for taking the time to explain erik!